# Receive and Return the averaging with a function?

Tags: c

I had a test, that I failed in the C language:

1. Create 10 random numbers.
2. Take the highest value.
3. Take the lowest value.
4. Make a function that will receive the two values and return the averaging number.

And I have no idea how to make the 2. 3. and 4. conditions so please if anyone could give me the code and maybe a little explanation so I can study it I would be really grateful thanks.
English is not my native language so sorry if it is badly written.

I only have the 1. condition:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h> 

int main() { 
    int a, b; 
    srand(time(NULL)); 
    for (a = 1; a <= 10; a += 1) { 
        b = rand() % 10 + 1; 
        printf("%d ", b); 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: this is the code

`#include <stdio.h>    
 #include <stdlib.h>    
 #include <time.h>    
 int main()    
 {    
 int a,b;    
 srand(time(NULL));    
 for(a=1;a<=10;a+=1)    
 {    
  b=rand()%10+1;    
  printf("%d ",b);    
 }    
 return 0;    
}`

Comment: Please add that to the body of the question using the edit link.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

guess you're just getting started good luck with your course!!!

What this program does is grab a "random" seed depending on your system time and uses that to generate 10 random numbers, then it checks each and every one to find the lowest and highest.
To define the range of numbers you wish to use from 0 to NUM_RANGE-1 just change the define good luck!!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <time.h>

#define NUM_RANGE   1000

double average(double number1, double number2);

int main(void) {
    int high_number, low_number;
    int counter, my_random_number[10];
    double result;

    srand(time(NULL)); //create random seed 

    for (counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++)  //creating number
        my_random_number[counter] = rand() % NUM_RANGE;

    low_number = my_random_number[0]; //avoid random value from affecting;
    high_number = my_random_number[0];

    for (counter = 1; counter < 10; counter++) { //finding numbers
        if (my_random_number[counter] > high_number)
            high_number = my_random_number[counter];
        if (my_random_number[counter] < low_number)
            low_number = my_random_number[counter];
    }
    result = average(high_number, low_number);

    printf("The average of the high and low number is %lf\n", result);

    return 0;
}

double average(double number1, double number2) {
    return (number1 + number2) / 2;
}
```

IMPORTANT THIS IS ALL DONE IN `main` SO THAT YOU UNDERSTAND THE CONCEPT DIVIDE THE PROGRAM INTO FUNCTIONS. The whole point of `main` is to read it and understand what the program does

Comment: thank you i really appreciate it and yes i just started and i don't really understand your code xD